# Angular2 calling a function in a sibling component

Tags: angular

**Component A**

I have a form with a button which should call a service class. The service returns an extracted JSON result.

```
compare() {
    this.getResults();
}

getResults() {
    this.resultService.getResults()
        .subscribe(
            results => this.results = results,
            error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Template of A:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="compare()" #compareForm="ngForm">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h1>Disk Forensics</h1>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="resourceA">Disk A</label>
            <select ngbDropDown class="form-control" id="resourceA" required [(ngModel)]="resourceA" name="resourceA">
                <option *ngFor="let r of disks" [value]="r.id">{{r.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="resourceB">Disk B</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="resourceB" required [(ngModel)]="resourceB" name="resourceB">
                <option *ngFor="let r of disks" [value]="r.id">{{r.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <button type="button" (click)="compare()">Compare</button>

        <div class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</div>
    </div>

    <h4>Mode</h4>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="diffmode" id="diffmode1" value="diffmode1" checked>
            different
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="diffmode" id="diffmode2" value="diffmode2">
            identical
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="diffmode" id="diffmode3" value="diffmode3">
            Left only
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="diffmode" id="diffmode4" value="diffmode4">
            Right only
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Service Class**

```
public getResults(): Observable<Result[]> {
    let body = JSON.stringify('{}');

    var options:RequestOptionsArgs = {
      body: "{}"
    }

    return this.results = this.http.get(this.url, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

**Component B**

Is just to display the results from the service

result.component.html:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>Results:</h1>
    <div>
        <p *ngFor="let r of results; let i=index">
            {{i + 1}}: {{r}}
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</div>
</div>
```

result.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Result } from "../models/result";
import {ResultService} from "../services/result.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'diff-result',
    templateUrl: './diff-result.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./diff-result.component.css'],
    providers: [ResultService]
})
export class DiffResultComponent implements OnInit {


    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private resultService: ResultService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getResults()
    }

    getResults() {
        this.resultService.getResults()
            .subscribe(
                results => this.results = results,
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

What I'd like is to trigger from the compare()-function that the service is being called and the result.html is updated with the results.

Since this is a sibling component, assuming I can't use the ViewChild-attributes.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Actually I'd like to pass data to a property of another component. In the getResults() function of Component A instead of this.results I'd like to pass the results to the property of Component B.

Comment: Why component B isn't calling the service? Please show that template of Component A..

Comment: @mxii, please find the updated template. Thanks

Comment: i've tried also:

button type="button" (click)="b.getResults()">Compare</button>

Marking the template like this:
<diff-result #b></diff-result>

But I get:
inline template:17:30 caused by: Cannot read property 'getResults' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a public `Subject` in your service.

Component A will trigger the comparison and Component B will consume the result.

Take a look at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/5vny5d4rfudq06qrJAOR?p=preview

```js
import {Component, NgModule, Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

 public ResultsSubject = new Subject<string>();

 public getResults() {
   this.ResultsSubject.next('data...');
 }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmpA',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>Component A</h3>
      <button (click)="_srvc.getResults()">trigger service!</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AComp {
  constructor(private _srvc: MyService) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmpB',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>Component B</h3>
      <p>
        {{_results}}
      </p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class BComp {

  _results = '';

  constructor(private _srvc: MyService) {
    this._srvc.ResultsSubject.subscribe(
      res => this._results = res,
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <my-cmpA></my-cmpA>
    <my-cmpB></my-cmpB>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, AComp, BComp ],
  providers: [MyService],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks mxii, I tried your example and it worked. However I had issues with Subject in regard with http.get() where it returns an Observable<Response> and in Subject I defined Subject<Result[]> where Result was an own model. I tried it on several ways and could get it done so I decided to move on and merge the 2 components. Thanks though for your support!

Comment: yw! Sounds like you missed the `.map()` function. Anyway, gl! :)

Comment: No, I used the .map() function. This returns the Observable<Response>, however in Subject  I defined Result[] as my type. Anyway :)

Comment: Your `types` are just for editing and compile-time checks .. during run-time there are no types! It's JavaScript! :)